# Ubuntu: How to upgrade ubuntu 11 to ubuntu 13?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

ubuntu 11(Natty) is no longer supported.

When try to use apt-get update, there are a lot of not found errors?

Comment: [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) on Ask Ubuntu answers this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about upgrading Ubuntu. Try [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 is apparently not "supported" anymore... it was not a LTS (Long Term Support) release (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/ubuntu-11-04-support-ends-today)

There seems to be an option of "updating" things on "old-releases" (but they are not actively maintained/updated anymore), by editing your source repositories location: https://askubuntu.com/questions/101479/are-existing-updates-available-after-end-of-support.

However, if you want to update to a 2013 version, probably the best you can do is to backup your data and configurations and install a new version from scratch. Pay attention to the fact that non-LTS versions stop being supported after around 2 years.